# How to get two objects containing greatest values within array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, arraylist, func

in jquery:

```
var arr = [{name:"a",val:3},{name:"b",val:6},{name:"c",val:7},{name:"d",val:8}];
```

How to output this

```
[{name:"c",val:7},{name:"d",val:8}]
```

Note: of course the positions of objects is not constant.

Comment: You're gonna need a for loop and temp variable. Should get you going

Comment: There has to be some criteria/condition based on which you want to filter the items..

Comment: Greatest two values thats the condition .. please provide code example of ur idea

Comment: @AhmedAborady please provide something YOU'VE tried and we'll lead you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you don't need jQuery for this one.

```
arr.sort(function(a,b){ return a.val < b.val});

//arr[0] now contains object with the maximum
//arr[1] now contains object with the second greatest value
```

If you are interested in more verbose javascript utilities for arrays, objects and more, check out lodash or underscore.js:

https://lodash.com/
http://underscorejs.org/

Comment: You'd can `slice(0, 2)` to get the both of them into an array.

Comment: Actually with numbers, the function should be returning `b.val - a.val` as the sort function expects `1`, `0`, or `-1` ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/h2a7p1qu/)).

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing why you want these particular items, without knowing any other context, with only being asked to create some output (do you want the items in an array, or do you want to output this as text?) here is a throw away piece of code which might help you figure out what you actually want to do.

```js
var arr = [{name:"a",val:3},{name:"b",val:6},{name:"c",val:7},{name:"d",val:8}];
var tarr = [];
function fetch() {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i].name == "c" || arr[i].name == "d") {
            tarr[tarr.length] = arr[i];
        }            
    }
    var output = document.getElementById("results");
    output.innerHTML += "[";
    for (var j = 0; j < tarr.length; j++) {
        output.innerHTML += "{name:\"" + tarr[j].name + "\",val:" + tarr[j].val + "}";
        if (j < tarr.length - 1) {
          output.innerHTML += ",";
        }
    }
    output.innerHTML += "]";
}
fetch();
```

```html
<div id="results"></div>
```